# multiple scrolling divs in flexbox layout with constrained parent container?

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I am trying to create the following:
a .mainFlex container which contains 3 flex boxes.

- **box1** is never going to be very tall. It needs not to scroll, expand, or shrink. Lets say it can take up 10% of the container height.
- **box2** has variable content. If it only has a line or two, it should only be as tall as that content. If it has more, it may expand up to 40% height, leaving a minimum of 50% container height for box3. Overflow should be scrollable on box2 once its max of 40% container height is reached.
- **box3** should take as much as 80%, as little as 50% of parent container height. Overflow should be scrollable.

**codepen here:** 
http://codepen.io/JWindels/pen/XbLLop

```
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="FCpanel"><div class="mainFlex col-xs-8"><div class="box1">This is some text</div><div class="box2">some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sk  sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk</div><div class="box3">is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sd sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk s some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk s</div></div><div class="mainFlex col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"></div></div></div></div>
```

**My problem:**
setting max-heights in percentages do not enable overflow:scroll to function. However, if I use em measurements for max-height in box2 and box3, I run the risk of having content in box3 that exceeds the height of the parent container, and cannot be seen, even with the scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work properly:

```css
.FCpanel > .mainFlex > .box1 {
  max-height: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.FCpanel > .mainFlex > .box2 {
  max-height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.FCpanel > .mainFlex > .box3 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
.FCpanel {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.FCpanel > .mainFlex {
  background: #ebf6fd;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.5875em #666;
  font-family: "OpenSans-Bold", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid 1px #428cca;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 516px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.FCpanel > .mainFlex > .box1 {
  max-height: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.FCpanel > .mainFlex > .box2 {
  background-color: #0f0;
  max-height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.FCpanel > .mainFlex > .box3 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="FCpanel">
      <div class="mainFlex col-xs-8">
        <div class="box1">This is some text</div>
        <div class="box2">some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sk sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk</div>
        <div class="box3">is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sd sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text
          sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk s some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his
          is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sfjk fsdjk his is some text sdjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk sjks sjkhsdkjh sadk;s sjks jsdh dsk shjk sdjkl fsdjkl fsjk jk s</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainFlex col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, `height: auto; flex-basis: auto` makes box1 and box2 to be as tall as the content.

Then `max-height` prevents them from growing to much.

Note Flexbox adds `auto` as the initial value of `min-height`, so in order to make `max-width` work properly you can use `min-height: 0`, or set `overflow` to anything but `visible`, which makes `min-height: auto` behave like `min-height: 0`.

In this case I use `overflow: auto`, which will produce scrollbars only when necessary.

Finally, setting `flex: 1` to box3 makes it grow to fill remaining space (`flex-grow: 1`), ignoring its contents (`flex-basis: 0%`).

Note the boxes will have the default `flex-shrink: 1`, but they will never shrink because their height won't be greater than 100%. Feel free to set `flex-shrink: 0` if you want to be sure.

Comment: Oriol, listen to me. The human world is a mess. Life under the sea is better than anything they got up there!

Seriously though, thanks so much =]

Comment: @AustinWindels Did my answer make you want to live under the sea?  You're welcome :) I have added some explanations.